# How to figure out Hyperledger Fabric version from container images

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I got a hyperledger fabric implementation that uses the following docker images (taken from docker-compose files):

```
hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.5.5
hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4.5
hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4.0
hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.4.5
```

Let's say I want to set up a development environment, which fabric version should I set up? 2.4.0? 2.4.5?

I've gone through the official doc releases data, but it doesn't state which images its using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Fabric v2.4.x releases should have the same set of capability. The third digit is a patch release version, and indicates that bug fixes are included. Essentially [semantic versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Semantic_versioning).

I would expect the versions of the core Fabric images (other than the CA) to be consistent. So using exactly the same versions of fabric-orderer, fabric-peer and fabric-tools. In your case, all at version 2.4.5. In general I would suggest always using the latest patch release.

You might find it easier to download the latest set of Docker images for Fabric using the Fabric install script, as described on this documentation page:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html